# Can't add items to ListView after ListView.Clear

Tags: vb.net, listview, items

So, I'm currently working on a game called `uToob`, which should be a YouTUbe-Simulation-Kinda game. The game should be realistic, so I programmed a kinda-OS for the game. Now I'm working on the `Internet Explorer`, which should be the web browser. When you open it, there's some `PictureBoxes` you can click to go to different "Websites" using a TabControl. There also is a Bank-Site. The problem is: When I click the Home Button on the bank site, which brings me back to the Main Page, and then go back to the bank page, all the transactions in the `ListView` are gone.

Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/qCWzPVH8
- The important `Subs` for this issue are called `SwitchBank`, which is triggered when you click the bank button on the main page, and `HomeBank`, which is triggered when you click the home button on the bank page.

Any help would be apprechiated!

Mika // OneByte_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you bother to read the relevant documentation?  Obviously you didn't.  You could have solved this issue for yourself in less than a minute if you had.

> You can use this method to remove all items and columns from the
>   ListView control without having to call the individual Clear methods
>   from the ListView.ColumnHeaderCollection and
>   ListView.ListViewItemCollection classes.

Do you want to clear all the columns?  I'm guessing not, so why would you call a method that does so?  If all you want to do is clear the items then that's what you should do, i.e. call `Clear` on the `Items` collection.

In future, make sure you read the relevant documentation first when you have an issue.  VS has a Help menu for a reason.